# Is it acceptable to have non-<li> elements inside a <ul> in HTML?

Tags: html, list, flexbox

I'm working on a project where I find it convenient to include elements other than `<li>` inside a `<ul>`. Is this semantically correct and acceptable in HTML or should I make the elements start with `<li>`?

I have below one list inside another one. The element I am trying to put has the tag `<textarea>`.

Example:

```
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="category">what + how + who</li>
            <ul class="subcategories">
                <li>WHAT do we do?</li>
                <textarea class="input"></textarea>
                <li>HOW do we do it?</li>
                <li>WHO do we serve?</li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) or [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) is a valid child of `<ul>`.

[Valid children are as follows...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul#technical_summary)

- [`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)
- [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)
- [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)